# How to understand "乒乓大方卜"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, food

[image]

I saw a brand (Hup Seng) of sugar crackers with the Chinese character "乒乓大方卜". Though I recognise every character here, I do not see how these five characters make sense together. Does not "乒乓" mean "table tennis"? What does "大方卜" mean then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「乒乓大方卜」 refers to a biscuit-product-line name **[cap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cap#Indonesian) ping pong** (Malay for *ping-pong brand*, forming the 「乒乓」 part) and *large square thin crackers* (「大方薄餅乾」; 「餅乾」 is omitted and 「卜」 is a phonetic substitution of 「薄」, meaning *thin*, forming the 「大方卜」 part).

---

- The *Hup Seng* (合成) company has [three snack product lines](https://www.hupseng.com/our-products-1), one of them named **cap ping pong**

  [image: Hup Seng product lines]

  On their website (https://www.hupseng.com/timeline), it says

  > ##### 1958
  >
  > Hup Seng started research and development to bring biscuit lovers the best biscuit one can taste. Hence, we started producing the Ping-Pong crackers.
  >
  > The name ‘Ping Pong’ derives from the success of China being the champion of the World Table Tennis Championship that year. The crackers have been widely loved by Malaysians, leaving a significant impact across generations
- Google image search of 「卜餅乾」

  > [image: Google image search of 「卜餅乾」]

  Google image search of 「薄餅乾」

  > [image: Google image search of 「薄餅乾」]